# How to recover folder deleted with rm -rf from \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\username

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've accidentally deleted some important folders from my WSL Ubuntu environment using the `rm -rf` command. The specific path was `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\myusername\myfoldername`. I'm aware of the TestDisk tool, which requires booting Ubuntu from a USB drive for the recovery process.

However, I'm looking for alternatives that might allow me to recover these deleted folders without needing to boot from a USB. Are there any other effective methods or tools that can be used directly within Windows or the WSL environment for this purpose?

**Environment:**

- Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
- Ubuntu

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I've considered TestDisk, but it requires booting from USB.

Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I thought testdisk has windows versions too... [Yes, it has downloads for dos, windows, linux, mac...](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) At any rate, if they're very important files, do try to stop writing to the drive or you could overwrite what's left.